# Computar la media de una variable en R, en función de los niveles de otra variable/factor

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero calcular en R la media de la temperatura máxima (`Max.TemperatureC`) los fines de semana y entre semana (`findesemana`, factor con dos niveles Si (= fin de semana) y No (entre semana)), o séa, dos medias de la temperatura máxima distintas, la del fines de semana y la de entre semana

He conseguido hacer un boxplot de la temperatura máxima en función de sí es entre semana o fin de semana:

```
plot(datos$findesemana, datos$Max.TemperatureC, xlab = "Fin de Semana", ylab = "Max.Temperatura")
```

Adjunto el boxplot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿puedo sacar la media de cada uno de los boxplots? O sea, la media de la `Max.TemperatureC` en función de `Si` (fin de semana) y de `No` (entre semana)? Gracias!

Comment: primero que nada aquí no le hacemos la tarea/el trabajo a nadie... si quieres que te la hagan vas a tener que pagarle a alguien en un sitio web que hagan tareas/trabajos... segundo si no entendiste que tienes que hacer deberías preguntarle a quien te lo asigno que te ayude a entender que es lo que realmente quiere que se haga... https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Una simple usando `aggregate()`

Uso como ejemplo los datos `mtcars`, que vienen incluidos en `R`.

```
aggregate(mpg~gear, data = mtcars, FUN = mean)
```

Que te regresa:

```
  gear      mpg
1    3 16.10667
2    4 24.53333
3    5 21.38000
```

La media de `mpg` condicional a `gear`.
La función tiene tres argumentos (las cosillas que le especificas entre los paréntesis).

`mpg~gear` indica las variables que usas y el orden de operación. Del lado izquierdo del símbolo `~` es la variable de la que quieres obtener la media, del lado derecho la variable categórica que define los grupos. Eso dentro de `R` es una fórmula y es un tipo de sintaxis especial para definir relaciones entre variables. Se usa sobre todo para especificar modelos.

`data = mtcars` indica que debe buscar esas variables en el data frame `mtcars`

`FUN =` es la función que va a aplicar. En este caso la media, pero podría ser `median` para la mediana, `sd` para la desviación estándar. Importante: cuando usas estas funciones dentro de una llamada a `aggregate` no se usan los paréntesis después de la función.

> Aclaración: la línea central del boxplot no indica la media, sino la mediana. En una distribución normal ideal (medida sin error) media y mediana coinciden, pero no confiaría con datos reales.